# hide empty row in gridview

Tags: c#, sql

I want to hide empty row in one particular column. I tried to but negative. Below is my code:

```
protected void gvDb_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow rw in gvDb.Rows)
    {
        if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.Cells[1].Text) | (rw.Cells[1].Text == "")))
        {
            rw.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that code throwing exception or not working as expected?

Comment: Your code go in rw.Visible = false?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < gvDb.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    var row = gvDb.Rows[i];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value)))
    {
        row.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

This will work,
use `for` instead of `foreach` to iterate all the rows except last row which is empty.